# How to rotate the text in a CATextLayer?

Tags: objective-c, catextlayer

I'm displaying some text in a `CATextLayer` but its to large to fit in the defined rect. I would like to have the text rotate slowly so it can all be read. I have no idea how to do that though. I'm hoping there is a relatively easy way to do this and if not that someone knows a url to an example or tutorial showing/teaching how to do such a thing.

```
    CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    NSRect labelRect;
    labelRect.origin.x = 20;
    labelRect.origin.y = -height / 3.5;
    labelRect.size.width = width - 40;
    labelRect.size.height = height;
    [label setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
    [label setFontSize: fontSize];  
    [label setFrame:labelRect];
    [label setString:@"Some really long menu item that won't fit"];
    [label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentLeft];
    [label setForegroundColor:whiteColor];
```

**update**: I guess what I'm trying to describe would be that the text itself rotates. something like the html marquee tag would do.

Comment: Just rotate CATextLayer. Use property `@property CATransform3D transform;`

Comment: @beryllium - I don't want to transform the label but want the text inside the label to rotate/animated slowly so the text can all be read. My understanding of the transform property is that it transforms the whole layer itself, unless I'm misunderstanding things.

Comment: I'm guessing from your reply to @beryllium that you have sublayers in your CATextLayer that you don't want transformed? If that's the case then his suggestion would work if you also applied the inverse transform on the sublayerTransform.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me it will help you try this....

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f(_userResizableView2.transform.b, _userResizableView2.transform.a);

CGFloat flip=((UITextView*)_userResizableView2.contentView).transform.a;
NSLog(@"Flip x: %f Y : %f",((UITextView*)_userResizableView2.contentView).transform.a,((UITextView*)_userResizableView2.contentView).transform.b);
CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);
NSLog(@"Degree :%f",degrees);
float radiansToRotate = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( -degrees );
CATransform3D zRotation;
zRotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radiansToRotate,0, 0, 1.0);
titleLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(zRotation,flip, 1, 1);
```